# Sending Complex Data to ASP MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been struggling to research an answer to this question as I cannot come up with the correct search terms.

Basically I have 2 `IEnumerable<T>`'s in my controller, below is the code for the attempt I made.

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<Room> allRooms = RoomHelper.FindAllRooms();

    foreach (var room in allRooms)
    {
        IEnumerable<Bunk> associatedBunks = RoomHelper.FindAssociatedBunksByRoom(room);
        if (associatedBunks.Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewData["Room_"+room.RoomId] = associatedBunks;
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to send them to the view in a way that I can do two `foreach` loops that will cycle through one set of data (in this case the `Room` objects and will then using the `Room.RoomId` key cycle through another `IEnumerable` which contains the associated data.

My view looks like this but is showing parse errors:

```
@foreach (var room in ViewBag.Rooms)
{
    <h2>@room.RoomName</h2>

    @if (ViewData["Room_" + room.RoomId].Count() > 0)
    {
        <ol>
            @foreach (var bunk in ViewData["Room_" + room.RoomId])
            {
                <li>@bunk.BunkId</li>
            }
        </ol>
    }
}
```

The end result I'm looking for in the HTML is something like:

```
<h2>Room 1</h2>
<ol>
    <li>Bunk 1</li>
    <li>Bunk 2</li>
</ol>

<h2>Room 2</h2>
<ol>
    <li>Bunk 3</li>
    <li>Bunk 4</li>
</ol>
```

What is the best practice in ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF5 to achieve this kind of result when passing "multidimensional" (is this multidimensional?) data?

Comment: I think I'm missing something when it comes to using the `@` syntax in views.

Comment: I would think that any time you need to send somewhat complex data to a view, you should create a ViewModel specifically for the view which caters to that views needs.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on `ViewData`. Store the data that you want to pass on to your view in a proper `ViewModel`:

```
public class RoomViewModel
{
     List<Room> Rooms { get; set;}

     ...
}
```

Store your data in one of those.

Your Controller method then returns an instance of it:

```
public RoomViewModel GetRooms(int someParameter)
{
    RoomViewModel result = new RoomViewModel();
    result.Rooms = RoomHelper.Something(someParameter);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Your `View` declares its model on top:

```
@model MyApplication.ViewModels.RoomViewModel
```

and hence you use it in your `View`.

```
<h2>@Model.Rooms.Count rooms found</h2>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a code block in your view instead of adding an '@' in front of each C# statement:

```
@{
 foreach (var room in ViewBag.Rooms)
 {
   @Html.Raw("<h2>" + room.RoomName + "</h2>");

  if (ViewData["Room_" + room.RoomId].Count() > 0)
  {
   @Html.Raw("<ol>");

   foreach (var bunk in ViewData["Room_" + room.RoomId])
   {
    @Html.Raw("<li>" + bunk.BunkId + "</li>");
   }

   @Html.Raw("</ol>");
  }
 }
}
```

You should avoid the use of @HtmlRaw("") as far as possible as it has a XSS vulnerability. But this should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

As per description given by you it seems that Bunk is associated with rooms. If that's the case then Bunk may have some id for pointing to room it belongs. Now you can create a ViewModel like this

```
public class BunkViewModel:Bunk
{       
    public BunkViewModel()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Bunk,BunkViewModel>();
    }

    //I'm assuming that you already have some id in bunk to point to room it belongs. 
    //But writing it here to make it clear
    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    //Use AutoMapper to Map
    public static BunkViewModel Map(Bunk source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Bunk,BunkViewModel>(source);    
    }
}
```

Now in your controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var result = new List<BunkViewModel>();
    var rooms = RoomHelper.FindAllRooms();
    var bunks = BunkHelper.GetAllBunks();

    foreach(var bunk in bunks)
    {
        var bunkViewModel = BunkViewModel.Map(bunk);
        var room = rooms.FirstorDefault(r=>room.RoomId == bunk.RoomId);

        bunkViewModel.RoomId = room.RoomId; //No need to set if you already have this id in bunk
        bunkViewModel.RoomName = room.RoomName;

        result.Add(bunkViewModel);
    }

    return View(result.);
}
```

Now in your view you can do like this

```
@model List<MyApplication.ViewModels.RoomViewModel>

@foreach(var bunk in Model)
{
    //Print it here as you want..
}
```